# Typo3 form displays as ###LABEL### ###FIELD###

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript, formwizard

I've made a form on a page using the Typo3 4.6 form wizard, but on the page it renders as

```
<!--  Mail form inserted: [begin] -->
 <fieldset class="csc-mailform">
 <div class="csc-mailform-field">###LABEL### ###FIELD###</div>
 </fieldset>
<!--  Mail form inserted: [end] -->
```

... instead of displaying a form. I'm completely new to Typo3. How do I get it working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to insert the static typoscript "Default TS (form)"! Goto your main typoscript template file or create a extension template on the current site (where the form is) and edit the whole template file so that you can insert the "Default TS (form)"!

Comment: And be sure to have "Include Static Templates After Basis Templates" ticked.

Answer (score 1):

Original answer does not work in Typo3 v 6.1.0

See http://forge.typo3.org/issues/50274

What helped was to disable Form extension as suggested in link above, then there is no need to include static typoscript.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason causing this problem is having the extension "form" installed. The "form" extension and the normal search plugin do not work together. Uninstalling "form" solved the problem for me.